# How to find the index of an element in a Vec of Results, stopping if an Err is found?

Tags: rust, error-handling, iterator

Suppose I have a collection of [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) items, like:

```rust
let items: &[Result<&str, u32>] = &[Ok("foo"), Err(444), Ok("bar")];
```

I need to find the index of the first element with the value `"bar"`. My first attempt looks like:

```rust
let bar_idx = items.iter()
    .position(|item| item? == "bar")?;
```

This won't work because of the `?` operator inside the closure.

I'm aware of the [`try_for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_for_each) method, which fails the entire collection if an `Err` is returned, but there is no such equivalent for [`position`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position), which is what I'm trying to do.

How can I implement this search?

EDIT:

I opened [an issue at Rust repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/libs-team/issues/361), because I believe `try_position` should exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build one on top of `try_for_each()`:

```rust
use std::ops::ControlFlow;
let item: ControlFlow<Result<usize, u32>> =
    items
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .try_for_each(|(idx, item)| match item {
            Ok(v) if *v == "bar" => ControlFlow::Break(Ok(idx)),
            Ok(_) => ControlFlow::Continue(()),
            Err(err) => ControlFlow::Break(Err(*err)),
        });
// Can replace by `ControlFlow::break_value()` once stabilized.
let item = match item {
    ControlFlow::Break(v) => Some(v),
    ControlFlow::Continue(()) => None,
};
```

But frankly, it's likely better to use a simple `for` loop:

```rust
let mut result = None;
for (idx, item) in items.iter().enumerate() {
    match item {
        Ok(v) if *v == "bar" => {
            result = Some(Ok(idx));
            break;
        }
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(err) => {
            result = Some(Err(*err));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The for-loop version becomes even simpler if you wrap it in a function returning `Result` and use `?` to exit early on error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38d015ec3a25c2eb1338f57db9aa2e70

Answer (score -2):

```rust
fn main() {
    let items: &[Result<&str, u32>] = &[Ok("foo"), Err(404), Ok("bar")];

    // find the index of the first element with the value "bar"
    let idx1 = items.iter().position(|x| x.is_ok_and(|x| x == "bar"));
    println!("{:?}", idx1);

    // or you can combine `enumerate`,`find` and `map` to find the index
    let idx2 = items.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .find(|(index, value)| {
            if **value == Ok("bar") {
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        })
        .map(|x| x.0);
    println!("{:?}", idx2);
}
```

Both print `Some(2)` here.If nothing found, print `None`.

Comment: `if <expr> { true } else { false }` is the same as just `<expr>`.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions errors out early when encountering an error, so I think this misses the point of the question.